# Maximum inductance of parallel circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, parallel

Three inductances, 1 henry, 2 henry and L henry are in parallel. Find value of L such that the equivalent inductance is maximum. At this value of L, what is the value of equivalent inductance?

Comment: What have you tried or what are your thoughts on this question; where did you get stuck trying to answer it?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking" because you have not clarified what aspect of the question you don't understand.

Comment: What's unclear? It's an assignment  problem, of course, and he has three inductors in parallel, two of which have an equivalent inductance of 666 millihenrys. The question is, basically, what value of inductance must the third inductor have to not decrease the total equivalent inductance.  Or, putting it another way, what value of inductance must the third  inductance have in order to maximize the equivalent inductance of all three ?  Sometimes inductance is hard to wrap one's head around, but in this phaseless instance, resistance is a perfect analogy for inductance and the math is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tricky :-)**

Since L1 and L2 are in parallel, their equivalent inductance will be

$$ Lt =\frac{L1 \times L2}{L1 + L2} = \frac{2H}{3H} \approx \text{ 0.67 henry}$$

Any inductance added in parallel will only decrease the equivalent inductance, so there is no inductance which, if connected in parallel, will maximize the inductance.

Comment: Many thanks for answer. 
As you explained, No need to add any inductance in parallel. 
No Inductance--- Does this mean infinite inductance or zero inductance?

Comment: infinite inductance

Comment: @payala: Since it's already maximal with the two parallel inductors in there, infinite inductance in parallel with that won't maximize it, it just won't change it.  Much.

Comment: @Vinay: For inductors in parallel,  the equivalent inductance is equal to the reciprocal of the sum of the reciprocals of the individual inductances, so we can write: $$ L_t = \frac{1} {\frac{1}{L1}+\frac{1}{L2}+\frac{1}{L3}}= \frac{1} {\frac{1}{1H}+\frac{1}{2H}+\frac{1}{L3}}$$ The tricky bit is getting \$ \frac{1}{L3}\$ to equal zero.

Comment: @Vinay: We mostly work for points here, so if you found my answer helpful you could upvote it and make me 10 points richer. You could also accept it as your favorite answer and get me 15 points. Or, neither...  In any case, before the brutes decide to destroy everything they don't understand, thanks for an interesting question.